# Retrieve information from a website without APIs

Tags: java, android, html

I'm developing an Android application, which is programmed in Java. I've worked with APIs before, however I was wondering if it's possible to retrieve information without an API.

For example, trying to retrieve the hours of operation [found here](http://dining.carleton.ca/locations/bakers/). If I click inspect element on the hours of operation, I can see that they are found under a heading called "Hours". Can I use these HTML tags to my advantage? I.e. grab that heading/paragraph, parse it, and retrieve the needed results.

Thank you!

PS. Apologies for the newbie question, I wasn't sure how to properly word it so that I can receive relevant Google results.

Comment: You will need to scrap the page. Make an HTTPRequest and parse the html received to find the data you need. There are some libraries like Jsoup that will facilitate your task, although parsing big amounts of html could slow down your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to add something to comment by @Luciano Rodríguez.

As you know you can read content of HTTP response and then parse it as HTML. As you mentioned you can access specific element and get its value.

Now the problem is how generic your application should be. If for example you want to get a couple of fields from one specific site you already have all tools. Get HTML, parse it using one of available HTML parsers to extract data and you are done.

However if you are building generic application that should support various sites and be configurable you have a problem.

First, you have to be able to extract any data from DOM. I am personally working now on similar task. I used HTMLCleaner to get DOM from HTML and XPath to configure interesting nodes. But it is not all. Modern sites are very dynamic. Very often the information is not generated at server site as HTML but is built dynamically by javascript running on client site. It is not simple to support such case. Generally on the top of my head there can be 2 approaches:

1. Use fully functional headless browser that will play the web application and create DOM. Then you can get data from DOM using XPath
2. Get data from the source, e.g. HTML, XML, JSON etc. This approach requires additional configuration for each site you want to support.

Comment: First, thanks for your additional comments. I'm looking to build a very specific application, just to get experience in this so I think I'm just gonna go with the scrapping of the HTML. One question I have is: in the link that I provided, the hours of operation are inside a <p> tag, however there are many <p> tags in that page. How does the scrapper know which one to grab? Or do I tell the scrapper I want the <p> that is found inside the <h3> that is found in X, etc.?

Comment: If you have to get just very specific tag you can even use regex to parse it. I believe that time format is pretty simple, so you can use regex like `<p>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}</p>` or something like that. Generally if you want more robust solution you should base your parsing on path, i.e. `<p>` that is located under `<h3>` as you said or even full path starting from the root `<html>` tag.